# Showing 80% line Boxplot in r

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I have a large dataset (25,00 records) of only numbers and I'd like to know its 80% threshold. Whenever I try to run `boxplot(data)` on it, the result is not clear because I have so many values:

[image: Unclear]

I tried to go around it and came up with `boxplot(data, outline = FALSE)` and the result is below:

[image: Clear]

So basically I was wondering about two things:

1) The upper line in the second picture represents 75% correct? If so, then how I can change the 75% to 80%.

2) Is my way of not showing the outliers is correct? Or maybe there is a more simple way of showing just the 80% threshold?

Sorry for not providing a reproducible example but I will edit if it will be necessary.

Comment: Which line is the upper line? You mean the whisker at the end of the dashed line or the top of the box? The upper whisker is drawn to minimum of i) 1.5*IQR or ii) the limit of the data. The upper edge of the box is the upper hinge. It is almost but not always the upper quartile of the data.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I meant the upper edge of the box. In this case it is 40. does it mean that 75% of the whole dataset is below 40?

Comment: Almost; as I said, it is not the upper quartile but the upper hinge. Read `?boxplot.stats` for what the difference is and where it is not the upper quartile.

Comment: If you are not sure about what is showing run `quantile(yourdata, probs=0.8)` for the 80% quantile

Comment: @mts That's exactly what I need. But when I run `quantile(data, probs=0.8)` it gives me this error `undefined columns selected`. When I change my `data` to a list and run it as `quantile(x, probs=0.8)` it gives me this error `'x' must be atomic`. Is it because maybe I need to sort the list first?

Comment: what is the structure of your data? run `str(data)` to find out

Comment: You can't pass a data frame to `quantile()`; the `undefined columns...` error comes if you do that.

Comment: @mts It is a data frame: `'data.frame':` I converted the data frame into a list using `x <- c(data)` but I still get an error whenever I try to run `quantile(x, probs=0.8)`

Comment: assuming you have only one column of data: `quantile(data[,1], probs=0.8)` should do the trick

Comment: also check the `range` argument in `?boxplot` that should tell you what you want. Choosing a larger range will enlarge your whiskers

Comment: @mts `80% 58` Perfect! So it means that every value >= 58 is at the remaining 20%, correct? Oh, and my values were not supposed to be sorted, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I would suggest you do this, but you can change the statistical summary used to draw the boxplot, and replace any of the stats with your own statistics.

For example, to do as you asked and draw the upper bound of the box at the 0.8 quantile of the distribution of `x` (instead of at the upper hinge), then we would do:

```
set.seed(10)
x <- rnorm(1000)
bps <- boxplot(x, plot = FALSE)
```

`bps` now contains:

```
> bps
$stats
             [,1]
[1,] -2.643849768
[2,] -0.677466940
[3,] -0.003001333
[4,]  0.728515646
[5,]  2.700636623

$n
[1] 1000

$conf
            [,1]
[1,] -0.07324983
[2,]  0.06724716

$out
[1] -3.001431  3.541140  3.012906 -3.012164

$group
[1] 1 1 1 1

$names
[1] "1"
```

and it is the `stats` component that we want to change

```
## Replace the 4th statistic (upper box)
bps$stats[4, 1] <- quantile(x, probs = 0.8)
```

Now we use the `bxp()` function to do the plotting - `boxplot()` uses this function internally, so we are not doing anything different here

```
bxp(bps)
```

This would give us:

[image]

The red line was added using

```
abline(h = fivenum(x)[4], col = "red", lty = "dashed", lwd = 2)
```

and is the upper hinge, i.e. where `boxplot()` would have drawn the upper edge of the box.

The reason I say I wouldn't suggest you do this as it changes the interpretation of the plot from what people would expect. If you do modify the boxplot, you'll need to explain your new conventions to the people to whom the plot is shown.

If we were being more careful about this, we'd also push the whiskers farther out now because the size of the box has increased. This will replace the lower and upper whiskers

```
bps$stats[c(1,5), 1] <- bps$stats[c(2,4), 1] + 
    (c(-1,1) * (1.5 * diff(bps$stats[c(2,4), 1])))
```

and replotting:

```
bxp(bps)
abline(h = fivenum(x)[4], col = "red", lty = "dashed", lwd = 2)
```

gives

[image]

Although now you have the problem of the outliers. So we should fix that too

```
ind <- bps$out > bps$stats[1,1] & bps$out < bps$stats[5,1]
bps$out <- bps$out[!ind]
bps$group <- bps$group[!ind]
```

which finally produces

[image]

Putting all of this together we have:

```
set.seed(10)
x <- rnorm(1000)
bps <- boxplot(x, plot = FALSE)
bps$stats[4, 1] <- quantile(x, probs = 0.8)
bps$stats[c(1,5), 1] <- bps$stats[c(2,4), 1] + 
    (c(-1,1) * (1.5 * diff(bps$stats[c(2,4), 1])))
ind <- bps$out > bps$stats[1,1] & bps$out < bps$stats[5,1]
bps$out <- bps$out[!ind]
bps$group <- bps$group[!ind]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this by generating the stats yourself and using `bxp` to plot it.

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
myBox <- list(stats = matrix(quantile(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1), ncol = 1)), n = 1000)
bxp(myBox)
```

This will have the hinges at the 20th and 80th centiles and the whiskers at the min and max. For your data, you may want alternative whiskers which you could create either with alternative quantiles or as some distance relative to the range between the 20th and 80th centiles. For the latter, you could do:

```
myBox2 <- list(stats = matrix(quantile(x, c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1), ncol = 1)), n = 1000)
myBox2$stats[c(1, 5)] <- myBox2$stats[c(2, 4)] + seq(-1, 1, 2) * diff(llmyBox2$stats[c(2, 4)])
```

Just to add, I entirely agree with Gavin that you would need to explain to anyone looking at this modified boxplot that it differed from the usual interpretation.

Comment: For some reason I receive this error `Error in z$stats[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions` whenever I run `bxp(myBox)`

Answer (score 1):

Answer1: the upper vertical line of the box shows the 3rd quartile which can but need not be very different from the 75% quantile (see comments below). If you are not sure, check with `fivenum(data[,1])` and `quantile(data[,1])`. Nick K and Gavin Simpson have shown you in their answers how to change that and I agree with them that it is dangerous to do so if you have no idea of boxplots. The most standard thing to do would be to change the `range` argument of `boxplot` but you'll need to indicate that.

Answer2: To give justice to your data you should show both plots: the first documents the outliers, the second your quantiles. 
To better represent all the data in one plot, you could try logscale:

```
boxplot(data, log="y")
```

this will give you an error with 0 values (as you likely have) so you could modify your data first:

```
data[which(data<= 1e-3)] = 1e-3
boxplot(data, log="y")
```

You have to check for your data if that gives you a nice plot.

Comment: It is not the 75th probability quantile *in all circumstances*. It depends on the data. The upper edge of the box is the upper hinge and this need not be the 75th probability quantile. Using the `x` from my answer, compare `boxplot.stats(x)$stats[4]`, `quantile(x, probs = 3/4)`, and `fivenum(x)[4]`. Note the `fivenum()` answer is the one reported by `boxplot.stats()`, not the value `quantile()` returns.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting comment! In fact boxplot shows Tukey's five number summary (https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Five-number_summary). That means the upper line of the box is the third quartile. The difference can be notable, e.g: `test = c(1:75, rep(200, 25)); fivenum(test); quantile(test);` I'll edit.